# How to sum the values of an MxN cell array?

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell

How can I make the sum of values in an `MxN` cell array? I used `cellfun('sum',CellArray{i})`
in which, `i` refers to the `MxN` index of the `CellArray`. But because I used it in a loop to count the number of blocks, it gives me error for being out of index.

What's the right way to do that please?

Comment: Could you provide a simple example cell, and the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I got your problem entirely right. You just want the total sum of all elements of a cell array? Assuming they are doubles, you first need to transform your cell array into a matrix, and then you can use the normal `sum` function.

```
% example data
xCell = num2cell( magic(10) )
```

gives you a a 10x10 cell array with some magic numbers from 1 to 100. 
The following creates a column-vector of all cell contents and sums them up:

```
S = sum([xCell{:}])

S =

        5050
```

which is the result good ol' Mr. Gauss didn't need Matlab for.

Alternatively if you're interested in the sum of all single rows or columns, you can use:

```
S = sum(cell2mat(xCell),dimension)   % dimension = 1 or 2 (or 3)
```

---

regarding your comment in your [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567240/how-to-ignore-the-complex-double-value-in-a-cell-array), that you actually have complex doubles:

use:

```
S = sum( real( [xCell{:}] ) )
```