# Sum M x N x P arrays in a R x 1 cell array element by element

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum, cell, cell-array

I have a R x 1 cell array (R is the number of rows), where each entry is a M x N x P array. How do I sum each of the arrays in the cell array so each entry is added within each M x N x P array? Can I do this with `cellfun`?

I found this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565290/how-to-sum-the-values-of-an-mxn-cell-array) in a similar question, but it returns a 1 x N x P array instead of the M x N x P array (see `B`) or I get an error "Error using cell2mat Too many input arguments" (see `C`).

```
M = 3;
N = 2;
P = 4;

A{1,1} = ones(M,N,P);
A{1,2} = 2*ones(M,N,P);
A{1,3} = 3*ones(M,N,P);

B = sum([A{:}]);
C = sum(cell2mat(A{:}),1);
```

I expect to get an M x N x P array but where each element is the sum of all of the elements in the i, j, k location of each of the cell entries.

```
B(1,1) = 6  % for all entries
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have a cell array in the first place? You could store all the equal-sized 3D arrays into a 4D array, and then what you want is just the sum over the fourth dimension.

If you really need a cell array, concatenate first along the fourth dimension to create the 4D array, then sum:

```
result = sum(cat(4, A{:}), 4);
```

If you need the cell array *and* concatenating into a 4D array gives you an error due to insufficient memory, you may need to resort to a loop:

```
result = zeros(size(A{1}));
for k = 1:numel(A)
    result = result + A{k};
end
```

You cannot use `cellfun`, at least not in a natural way, because `cellfun` applies a function to *each cell*, whereas you want to apply a function (sum) to *each entry* of all cells.

Comment: I have a cell array because I have a large R value, and creating a 4D array might lead to memory problems when doing the sum in general. I can make a function so that the other variables don't "get in the way" if need be.

Comment: So maybe use a 4D array to begin with. A cell array takes up more memory than the equivalent 4D array. Try for example `A = {ones(3,2,4), ones(3,2,4), ones(3,2,4)}; B = cat(4, A{:}); whos A B`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that.